# How to convert TimeStamp time from Firestore to time ago in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting time in format 05-Apr-2021 1:45:05 PM...I want to convert this time to (sometime) minutes ago

Comment: Instead of describing how your time looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of your database document.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can try storing the time in milliseconds with `System.currentTimeMillis()` or if you're inserting the data manualy, you can get the [currentMilliseconds](https://currentmillis.com/), then:

```
var creationTime: Long = 0
var timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(creationTime)
```